# Switch Statements Using String Input

Tags: c, sorting, switch-statement, scanf

```
char type;
printf("What type of sort would you like to perform?\n");
scanf("%s", &type);
switch(type)
{
case 'bubble':
    bubble_sort();
case 'selection':
case 'insertion':
default:
    printf("invalid input\n");
}
```

I am trying to create a program which sorts a list with either bubble, selection, or insertion sort based on the user's input.

I have to use switch case to do so.

I have defined a variable "type" before the switch statement, and then use the scanf function to assign it either "bubble", "selection", or "insertion".

However, when I run the code and type in "bubble", it does not carry out my bubble_sort function (not shown here) and instead resorts to the default case.

How can I fix this issue?

I am slightly uncertain as to whether 'char' was the correct way to define my "type" variable, or whether switch statements can only be used with single characters.

Also, I apologise if my code is not formatted correctly, as I am new to this site.

Let me know if I need to add any more information to this question!

Comment: First, you need a `break` after `bubble_sort();` else it falls though to the next case. Second, does this actually compile? In C strings should be in double quotes. And you can't use strings in a `switch`.

Comment: I just added a break, but the same problem still occurs. It does compile

Comment: Take your compiler's warning serious. Fix the code until no more warnings are issued ... *sigh*

Comment: Also, just noticed you declare `type` as a `char`, but treat it as a string in the `scanf`.

Comment: Hint: In C a single-quote is very, very, very different from a double-quote.

Answer (score 1):

Strings in C are a pointer type, so when you try to put a string value into a switch statement or if statement like that you are really just comparing two pointers and not the values that they are point to.

You need a function like `strcmp` or `strncmp` to compare what is actually being pointed to

So, it should look like something like this;

```
char type[200];
printf("What type of sort would you like to perform?\n");
scanf("%199s", type);
if (strcmp(type,"bubble")==0) {
    bubble_sort();
} else
if (strcmp(type,"selection")==0) {
    something_selection();
} else
if (strcmp(type,"insertion")==0) {
    something_insetion();
} else {
    printf("invalid input\n");
}
```

Comment: I see no strings in the OP's code beside the argument to `printf()` calls.

Comment: where would I add those functions?

Comment: @alk -- it is a new year, lets be forgiving and help people -- you right that he used single quotes, but that was clearly not his intent

Comment: OK, so make it really nice and do `"%199s"` ... ;-)

Comment: Sry, but still this does not seem to meet the requirements, as they read: "*I have to use switch case to do so*"

Comment: "Strings in C are a pointer type" - This is completely wrong! 1) C does not have a string type. 2) C "strings" are `char` arrays by convention, which are **not** pointers!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what are the reasons people downvoted this question? I would like to be able to improve my future questions or edit this question if that would benefit other readers.

Answer (score 1):

Since type is a char and the switch can use single characters, you could scan for one character using %c instead of %s

```
char type;
printf ( "What type of sort would you like to perform?\n");
printf ( "Enter b for bubble\n");
printf ( "Enter s for selection\n");
printf ( "Enter i for insertion\n");
scanf ( " %c", &type);
switch ( type)
{
    case 'b':
        bubble_sort();
        break;
    case 's':
        selection_sort();
        break;
    case 'i':
        insertion_sort();
        break;
    default:
        printf("invalid input\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in C. Because, to compare two strings, strcmp() function should be used. But there is no way to add function in switch case.